# Probability that a sub-sequence of i.i.d. zero-mean Gaussians is closer to a given point than the origin

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, vector-spaces, normal-distribution

I am given a sequence $X=\{X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\}$ of $n$ i.i.d. zero-mean Gaussian random variables $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$, and a vector $\mathbf{y}=\{y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_m\}$ of $m$ real numbers, where $m\leq n$.  I am trying to write down an expression for the probability $p$ of occurrence of a sub-sequence $X_S=\{X_i,\ldots,X_{i+m-1}\}$ in sequence $X$ such that the point it represents in the $m$-dimensional Euclidean space is closer (in Euclidean distance) to $\mathbf{y}$ as opposed to the origin.

I know that, due to the rotational symmetry of the Gaussian distribution, the probability of a point formed $m$ i.i.d. zero-mean Gaussian random variables being closer to $y$ can be expressed as $1-\Phi\left(\frac{\|\mathbf{y}\|}{2\sigma}\right)$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is the Euclidean norm and $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-t^2}dt$ is the cumulative distribution function of a standard Gaussian random variable.  I can thus use the union bound to upper-bound the probability that I am looking for as follows:

$$p\leq (n-m)\left(1-\Phi\left(\frac{\|\mathbf{y}\|}{2\sigma}\right)\right)$$

However, this seems awfully loose and I wonder if an exact expression is available.

Comment: Are you looking at the points $(X_i, X_{i+1},\ldots, X_{i+m-1})$ that are closer to $(y_i, y_{i+1},\ldots, y_{i+m-1})$ than to $(0,0, \ldots, 0)$? That is, the values of $y_1, y_2,\ldots, y_{i-1}, y_{i+m}, y_{i+m+1},\ldots, y_n$ are irrelevant in _this_ comparison?

Comment: There are only $m$ values in vector $\mathbf{y}$, and I am looking for *any* sub-sequence $(X_i,X_{i+1},\ldots,X_{i+m-1})$ that is closer to $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_m)$ than to $(0,0,\ldots,0)$. This is related to synchronization problems in communications...

Comment: Got it! You are trying to find the fixed sync pattern $\mathbf y$ in the received signal. But you might want to consider a different model in which you have to choose between $n-m$ hypotheses instead of making binary decisions on each.

Comment: Right, the binary decision on each hypothesis is suboptimal, though there are $n-m+1$ hypotheses, since I allow for the possibility of the *absence* of the sync pattern $\mathbf{y}$. The expression I seek is one for the "false alarm" probability that a $\mathbf{y}$ is "detected" while it's not present. Unfortunately, I can't think of anything other than the union bound above...